# Android - Default value of Recyclerview mHasFixedSize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I understand the concept of the mHasFixedSize field, however, I'm not sure what it's default value is (true or false). I could create a simple PoC and test, but:

1. Having the answer here can help other people (might end up creating a PoC and answer my own question);
2. I'd like to understand how someone found out (I tried looking at the code of RecyclerView.java, but it's always hard for me to find things on those codes and having a perception of how someone looked at this code (or any other place) to find it can be helpfull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can find out what is this default value is exactly how you were doing: Looking it up on the `RecyclerView` class you are using in your project. It's important that the code you are inspecting is the one in your project, not a version of this class you got online, for example, because it could be from a different version you are using in your project. A good way to go to this class, on windows, it would be to `CTRL + Right Click` above the name of the class in a place it's been used.

Once you are in there, you can look for the `mHasFixedSize` field and see it's usages. In my case (RecyclerViewVersion 1.1.0) it was used in those places along the class file:

```
public class RecyclerView extends ViewGroup implements ScrollingView, NestedScrollingChild2, NestedScrollingChild3 {

    // ..

    boolean mHasFixedSize;

    // ..

    public void setHasFixedSize(boolean hasFixedSize) {
        mHasFixedSize = hasFixedSize;
    }

    // ..

    public boolean hasFixedSize() {
        return mHasFixedSize;
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {

        // ..

        if (mLayout.isAutoMeasureEnabled()) {
    
            // ..
    
        } else {
            if (mHasFixedSize) {
            
                // ...
            
            }
    
            // ...

        }

        // ...
    
        void triggerUpdateProcessor() {
            if (POST_UPDATES_ON_ANIMATION && mHasFixedSize && mIsAttached) {

                // ...
    
            } else {
    
                // ...

            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when we look at this code, we see that the only place where this variable is being updated is on it's setter (`setHasFixedSize`) and getting used to kotlin, a person might think that the atribute `mHasFixedSize` has no default value because of that, however, in Java, after defining a primitive value without setting it's to an specific value on its declaration, a default value will be set automaticaly, and on the case of a boolean atribute, it will be `false`.
So, in this context, if the user does not set it to true, the `RecyclerView` class treats it as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It has default value as false. You can also change it to true in order to improve your view.